# Vue TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why `this` is undefined here? On logout click this is the error shown in the browser console `TypeError: this is undefined`

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import AuthModule from "@/store/auth";
import Store from "@/store";

const authModule = getModule(AuthModule, Store);

@Component({})
export default class App extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log("App mounted");
  }
  onLogoutClick() {
    authModule.logout().then(function() {
      this.$router.push("/login");
    });
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
     methods: {
       onLogoutClick() {
        let self = this
        authModule.logout().then(function() {
          self.$router.push("/login");
        });
      }
```

Comment: Passing this explicitly via a variable works. But, I was looking for the reason for `this` to be `undeifined`

Comment: maybe you need to write into methods your onLogoutClick function, but i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Using an arrow function to the anonymous function solves this. As arrow functions bind this to the lexical scope's `this` (in this case `onLogoutClick`'s this).

```js
onLogoutClick() {
    authModule.logout().then(() => {
      this.$router.push("/login");
    });
}
```